# Not sure how to fix this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, exc-bad-access

So I have a Task entity class (Core Data) and I'm trying to overwrite the setter for one of its strings (timeIntervalString), so it can be displayed in the detail text label of a table view cell. For some reason I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error like this:

[image]

The [Tasks timeIntervalString] goes on until like 37355...

Here is my code:

```
-(NSString *)timeIntervalString{

    NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(self.timeInterval);
if ((seconds/3600) == 0){
    if (((seconds/60) % 60) == 1) {
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u MIN", ((seconds/60) % 60)];
    } else {
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u MINS", ((seconds/60) % 60)];
    }
} else if ([self.conversionInfo hour] == 1) {
    if (((seconds/60) % 60) == 0){
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u HR", (seconds/3600)];
    } else if (((seconds/60) % 60) == 1) {
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u HR %u MIN", (seconds/3600), ((seconds/60) % 60)];
    } else {
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u HR %u MINS", (seconds/3600), ((seconds/60) % 60)];
    }
} else {
    if (((seconds/60) % 60) == 0) {
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u HRS ", (seconds/3600)];
    } else if (((seconds/60) % 60) == 1){
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u HRS %u MIN", (seconds/3600), ((seconds/60) % 60)];
    } else {
        self.timeIntervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u HRS %u MINS", (seconds/3600), ((seconds/60) % 60)];
    }
}
return self.timeIntervalString;
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: Semi-unrelated design question: outside of this method definition, do you ever set the value of timeIntervalString? Thinking about whether you even need to set the value of timeIntervalString rather than just returning it and marking this as a readonly property.

Comment: no i dont actually set it, i only display it. but i do set the timeinterval

Comment: Along the lines of what Esker said, there's probably no need to store this value in `_timeIntervalString`.  I'd declare your property as readonly and dynamic, skip the assignment and just return the formatted value.  This will save you some memory from an unnecessary instance variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return self.timeIntervalString` will just recursively call that same `timeIntervalString` method.

What you probably want is `return _timeIntervalString`.

Explanation: `self.timeIntervalString` is property accessor syntatic sugar, it's the same thing as `[self timeIntervalString]`, which will invoke the `-(NSString *)timeIntervalString` method you have defined here. The `return _timeIntervalString` change will make it so you are directly accessing the instance variable instead of invoking the property accessor recursively. This is a general pattern you should follow in any custom property accessor method you write.

*Edit*: based on discussion in comments, it would be even better to mark this as a readonly property and never actually set the value:

In your .h file:

```
@property (readonly) NSString *timeIntervalString;
```

In your .m file:

```
-(NSString *)timeIntervalString {
    NSString *value;
    // insert here the body of your timeIntervalString method, as you
    // originally wrote it, but replace all occurences of:
    // self.timeIntervalString = ...
    // with this: value = ...
    return value;
}
```

Comment: that makes sense! however, xcode is giving me "Use of undeclared identifier _timeIntervalString". It's undeclared because its Core Data and its set as @dynamic timeIntervalString. Thoughts?

Comment: You might need a `@synthesize timeIntervalString = _timeIntervalString` just after the @implementation line in your .m file. But, see my edited answer for an improved solution.

Comment: Actually variables are automatically synthesized with the underscore notation now, so if it is declared as a strong property, `@synthesize timeIntervalString` would work.

Comment: In the latest versions of xcode, you dont even need to include the @synthesize because it is done automatically.

Comment: I thought if you explicitly have `@synthesize someVarName` it would default to the old underscoreless naming convention for the ivar, for backward compatibility?

Comment: There is no need to `@synthesize` anything.  Just use a local variable.  Since the value is derived every time that method is called, using an instance variable or property is a waste of memory.

Comment: I missed the note about this being Core Data in the comments above, thus my suggestions about @synthesize and _timeIntervalString were a little off.

Comment: @esker Wouldn't matter if it was Core Data or not;  a method that returns a derived, always computed, value does not need a backing ivar (unless the method computes the value once and stores it away for future retrieval).

Comment: Right, the `@synthesize` is not needed for the alternative implementation in my answer, it's using a local var instead. My `@synthesize` suggestion was for the initial answer where it's still setting an ivar before thinking about the idea of making it a readonly property.

Comment: Just a heads up about properties of NSManagedObject subclasses - the compiler will NOT automatically synthesize the property. You need to explicitly @synthesize properties of NSManagedObject subclasses. This is because creating the ivar is often not what the programmer would want. It's probably why you got `Use of undeclared identifier _timeIntervalString`